# How to convert any time zone 8am into utc time

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

How can I convert any time zone 8 AM into UTC time with moment or javascript

```
moment("8:00:00","h:mm:ss").tz('time_zone).utc().toString()
```

I tied this but now working. Any solution?

Comment: You are missing a `'` after `time_zone` in the code you shared. There is no need to call `tz(time_zone)` function, your code seems fine, why you are saying that is not working?. If  you want, you can use [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) instead of `toString()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you meant the user's local time zone, you should use this:

```
moment("8:00:00","H:mm:ss").utc().format()
```

- `H` is for a 24 hour clock, `h` is for a 12 hour clock.  Though it wouldn't necessarily matter for 8am, there should be *some* way to know you didn't mean 8pm.  (This assumes 8pm would be `20:00:00`).
- You don't need moment-timezone's `tz` function.  You don't really need moment-timezone at all unless your source data is in some *arbitrary* time zone rather than the user's local time zone.
- Use `format` instead of `toString`.  If you want the output in a *particular* format, refer to [the documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) for arguments you can pass to that function.

If you actually meant an arbitrary time zone with an IANA time zone identifier such as `America/New_York`, then instead it should be like this:

```
moment.tz("8:00:00","H:mm:ss","America/New_York").utc().format()
```

- With this one, you *do* need moment-timezone.

Lastly, if this is a new project targeting modern environments, the Moment team recommends you consider using [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) instead. Luxon takes its time zone support from the environment itself, and thus is much smaller in size as well.

```
luxon.DateTime.fromFormat('8:00:00', 'H:mm:ss', { zone: 'America/New_York'})
              .toUTC().toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a variable with the current date value you have for other regions (must be in date format) and use `.toUTCString()` method.

Sample code for IST to UTC is below:

```
var curdate = new Date("Fri Mar 29 2019 08:00:00 GMT+0530");

var UTCdate = curdate.toUTCString();
```

Comment: I don't have date, I have timezone only like America/New_York

Comment: Can you please provide a sample date with you?

Comment: I don't have any date just 8 AM and time zones

Comment: Try with Joda Time, it might help!
https://js-joda.github.io/js-joda/manual/ZonedDateTime.html